# NHibernate.PropertyAccessException was unhandled

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am new to NHibernate. Just started learning NHibernate.

I am getting for run-time error with my C# code

NHibernate.PropertyAccessException was unhandled

```
 Message=Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of NHibernateDemo.Customer
 InnerException: System.InvalidCastException
     Message=Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet`1[NHibernateDemo.Order]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[NHibernateDemo.Order]'.
```

Following is my C# code written for

```
public class Customer {
    public Customer()
    {
        MemberSince = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<Order> Orders { get; set; } 
}
```

It's hbm file is as follow

```
<class name="Customer" table="Customer" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="FirstName" />
    <property name="LastName" />

    <component name="Address" >
      <property name="Street" />
      <property name="City" />
      <property name="State" />
      <property name="Country" />
    </component>

    <set name="Orders" table="`Order`" order-by="Ordered desc">
        <key column="CustomerId" />
        <one-to-many class="Order" />
    </set>
</class>
```

```
public class Order {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Ordered { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Shipped { get; set; }
    public virtual Location ShipAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}


<class name="Order" table="`Order`">
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Ordered" />
    <property name="Shipped" />

    <component name="ShipAddress" >
        <property name="Street" />
        <property name="City" />
        <property name="State" />
        <property name="Country" />
    </component>

    <many-to-one name="Customer" column="CustomerId" />

</class>
```

If I change "set" section to "list" in Customer HBM file and do necessary changes in Customer class. Program is running correctly. Also if i remove "set" section from Customer HBM file; it is working.

Can you please help me to find what is wrong with "set" section of Customer HBM file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is almost correct, but the `ISet` interface is not from System namespace but from `iesi` library (distributed with NHibernate)
So you can reference `iesi` and change your mapping:

```
public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

Or use the `IList<>`

and mapping with a `bag`

```
<bag name="Orders" table="`Order`" order-by="Ordered desc">
  <key column="CustomerId" />
  <one-to-many class="Order" />
</bag>
```

*NOTE also do not forget to init the **list**, just in case that entity is created via new operator and NOT loaded by NHibernate*

Comment: thanks Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Order> is working for me with "set"